# Reading one dimensional data from HDF5 file is slow

Tags: java, io, hdf5

I have a one dimensional datasets with lots of data (>30GB) and reading this files takes forever. I have tried to experiment with different chunking using H5repack but I can't really find anything that works well. I am reading the HDF5 files in Java with the Java Hdf5 library. I have also access to the code where the files are created.

1. How do I define a chunk to read for one dimensional data?? I understand the concept when you have matrices but for 1D?
2. I read everywhere about the access pattern of the data, but can't find a way to change that, is it possible?

Comment: - which chunk sizes did you try? 
- what's the access pattern ? 
- did you use compression ?

Comment: You have to add chunk size during write, not read, and 1D is not really different from ND, just set "chunksizes=(100,)" for 1D, if for ND it is "chunksizes=(100,100,100)" or whatever.

Comment: I've tried chunksizes ranging from 0.250M to 30M. How can I set an access pattern? I just have a function which basically says "read data from H5 file between these times". Both compression and no compression have been tried, no difference in reading speed.

I've now tried setting chunk size to 0.75M and chunk cache to 3M, this increased performance by 5x. But it's a bad feeling just doing trial and error instead of actually understanding how to specify the correct sizes according to my data!